# Is there any difference between joining tables and exists when filtering a table?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two tables A and B, and wanted to get a subset of A whose key k is also in B.

One option is by using join

```
select A.*
from A
join B on A.k = B.k
```

The other is

```
select A.*
from A
where exists (select *, B.k from B where A.k = B.k)
```

If the field k in B is unique, I feel they are the same. For for spark, is exist really considered by the subquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and the most truthful way is to `explain` both queries and compare their physical plans.

```
scala> println(spark.version)
2.4.0

scala> sql("select A.* from A join B on A.k = B.k").explain
== Physical Plan ==
*(2) Project [k#10L]
+- *(2) BroadcastHashJoin [k#10L], [k#6L], Inner, BuildRight
   :- *(2) Project [id#8L AS k#10L]
   :  +- *(2) Range (0, 10, step=1, splits=8)
   +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, false]))
      +- *(1) Project [id#4L AS k#6L]
         +- *(1) Range (0, 10, step=1, splits=8)

scala> sql("""select * from a where exists (select *, B.k from B where A.k = B.k)""").explain
== Physical Plan ==
*(2) Project [id#8L AS k#10L]
+- *(2) BroadcastHashJoin [id#8L], [k#6L], LeftSemi, BuildRight
   :- *(2) Range (0, 10, step=1, splits=8)
   +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, false]))
      +- *(1) Project [id#4L AS k#6L, id#4L AS k#6L]
         +- *(1) Range (0, 10, step=1, splits=8)
```

They seem alike, don't they?

> I feel they are the same

They are as proved above.

Comment: That's correct, the execution plan is one of the best way to compare performance and flow. In case running the same thing on SQl will show performance difference though. Since in case of 'exists' whole DB traversal won't happen.

Comment: What's _"on SQl "_?

Comment: I mean when one runs these in SQL

Comment: _"In case running the same thing on SQl will show performance difference though."_ but that's exactly what explain would tell you. If there's any full scan we'd have Scan node (not `Range` at the bottom).